# Trouble with AJAX not rending partial with argument - not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I imagine this is a basic question, but I am having trouble rendering a partial that I have rendered before. Here is what I am looking at currently, and I apologize for such a basic question: 
my Ajax request:

```
  $.ajax({
              url: "/result/"+choice1+"/"+choice2+"/"+choice3,
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "script",
              data: { choice1: choice1,
                      choice2: choice2,
                      choice3: choice3 }

            })
```

which works as it fires off: Processing by WelcomeController#algorthim as JS, with correct parameters.
Then it goes to that route,

```
 respond_to do |format|
    @result=result(@data,d, a)
    format.js {} 
end
```

goes to algorthim.js.erb
which is this file

```
(".output").append("<%= j render(:partial=> 'ranks', :locals=> { result: @result }) %>");
```

and then generates this partial:

```
<%= @result.inspect%>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p> test </p>
```

which should be outputed here:

```
<div class='output'>
                <p>Results:</p>
                <%= render "ranks" %>
            </div>
```

and is as seen by the console:
Rendered welcome/_ranks.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered welcome/algorthim.js.erb (1.8ms)

but I result in this:

```
<div class='output'>
                <p>Results:</p>
                nil
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p> test </p>
            </div>
```

I have tried also format.js{@result=@result} and format.js{render(:partial=> 'ranks', :locals=> { result: @result })} with no luck.

I was wondering if someone could help me!:)

Thank you and once again I apologize for the novice question.

@data is:

```
[#<Event id: 2563, name: "Go from Introvert to Extrovert by Socializing with ...", price: "Free", location: "1 Dundas St E", category: "Comedy/Hang Out", feeling: "None", time: "07:00 PM", created_at: "2013-12-07 04:12:26", updated_at: "2013-12-07 04:12:26", latitude: 43.3124212, longitude: -79.91762829999999>, #<Event id: 2690, name: "Yuk Yuk's", price: "Price not listed", location: "224 Richmond Street West, Toronto, ON, Canada", category: "Comedy", feeling: "None", time: "Time not listed", created_at: "2013-12-07 04:12:56", updated_at: "2013-12-07 04:17:34", latitude: 43.6498097, longitude: -79.3883142>]
```

d is: ["43.6426, 79.3871"]
a is: "Comedy"

Comment: Could you also post what `@data`, `d` and `a` are and the definition of `result` method?

Comment: Result does return a value, which I have checked with debugger. I posted above d and a and @data. Result does get fired as I checked with debugger, and changes based on input.

Comment: If result doesn't return a value then `@result` will be nil.  You need to return a value from `result()` so that `@result` will not be nil.

Comment: Result does return a value. For example it returns: [{"Friday Night Live @ ROM"=>94.16402889814924}, {"Jazz Wednesdays "=>88.43687123067886}, {"Classic Rock Fridays "=>85.98462836776537}]. The problem is not that result is nil, because it is never nil. THere is a problem somewhere else.

Comment: @vinodadhikary any advice?

Comment: Have you tried using the response returned in firebug or your js debugger. Please try it. Use your response and copy it in your console and execute it best way to debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer evidently was one of mistyping. on the (".output").append("<%= j render(:partial=> 'ranks', :locals=> { result: @result }) %>") I forgot the $, which caused the result never to show!. Alas, simple mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As the parameter name indicates,

```
(".output").append("<%= j render(:partial=> 'ranks', :locals=> { result: @result }) %>")
```

will pass *locals* to your partial. So instead of

```
<%= @result.inspect%>
```

you should have

```
<%= result.inspect%>
```

Comment: Was just about to write the same thing - you're passing local variables, not global ones